# Assigning value to a variable from query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a select query

```
select * 
from dbo.GetTableFromString ('2,www.google.com')
```

which returns this result:

```
2
www.google.com
```

Edit from comments: Function accepts comma separated values and returns a single column called `name`.

Now I want to store `2` in variable called `@ID` and `www.google.com` in `@Link`.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: You want to call the function with those parameters or you want to store the results in those parameters?

Comment: store the result in those two parameters

Comment: try this `declare @id int,@link varchar(200)
;with cte
as
(
 select * 
from dbo.GetTableFromString ('2,www.google.com')
)
select 
@id=id,@link=link
from
cte`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @SplitResults table(
     RowIndex int IDENTITY(1,1)
    ,Item varchar(200));

INSERT INTO @SplitResults 
    select * from dbo.GetTableFromString ('2,www.google.com');

SET @ID    =  (SELECT Item FROM @SplitResults WHERE RowIndex=1);
SET @Link  =  (SELECT Item FROM @SplitResults WHERE RowIndex=2);
```

Comment: Keep in mind, that there is no guarantee that `2` will end up in `@ID`. It can get `RowIndex=2`.

Comment: I don't know the `GetTableFromString` actually does, so only to make a hypothesis for the result from `GetTableFromString`.

Comment: @SuJun-Ming, `GetTableFromString` returns a table. This table is **not** ordered (as any table), so when you `INSERT` this table into `@SplitResults`, the order in which `RowIndex` identity values are generated is not defined. As a result, you may get `2` in the `@ID` variable or you may get `2` in the `@Link` variable. `www.google.com` may end up in the `@ID` variable and `www.google.com` may end up in the `@Link` variable.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov I know that, I just want to say that the `GetTableFromString` is user-defined function, It will keep the order for the result, and there are more methods to keep the output order (order for custom), this question is just only for rows in table into variables only.

Comment: so  is there any way to prevent the above concern? @VladimirBaranov

Comment: @user8034947, ideally, the `GetTableFromString` function should return two columns - one for value, second for its position in the original comma-separated string. If you know that the comma-separated string always has  a number and a text that never starts with a number, you can sort results of the current `GetTableFromString` function and rely on number being sorted before the text link. In other words, if you can't have a proper `GetTableFromString` function, then you need to rely on your knowledge of the data to deduce what is what.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @ID int, @link nvarchar(max);
select @ID = ID, @link = Link
from dbo.GetTableFromString ('2,www.google.com')
```

I suppose columns are returning the function dbo.GetTableFromString id and link. If they are not replaced by the correct column names..

Comment: function returns a single column 'name'

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
declare @str nvarchar(200)
set @str= '2,www.google.com'
declare @len int

SELECT @len=CHARINDEX(',', @str); 
SELECT SUBSTRING( @str,0, @len ) 'id'
SELECT SUBSTRING( @str,@len+1, LEN(@str) )'link'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Charindex`

```
DECLARE @TextValue varchar(100) = '2,www.google.com'
DECLARE @ID int
DECLARE @link varchar(100)

SELECT  @ID = substring(@TextValue, 0, charindex(',',@TextValue)),
      @link = RIGHT(@TextValue,len(@TextValue) - charindex(',',@TextValue)) 


SELECT @ID, @link
```

return

```
2   www.google.com
```